# Changing the focus of this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to write a caption for my work Instagram account. I work for a ski holiday company and it's a photo of one of our guest's children.

> Wonderful photos from Chalet Augustine guests, Mike and Anne. Their children look great in their ski suits!

The problem with what I've written is the fact the first sentence makes it sound like the photos are of them (Mike and Anne) when they are actually taken by them but the photos are of their children.

Comment: It’s fine as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can rephrase it this way:

> Wonderful photos taken by Chalet Augustine guests, Mike and Anne. Their children look great in their ski suits!

or something like this:

> Wonderful photos of our Chalet Augustine guests's children who look great in their ski suits! Thanks to their parents, Mike and Anne, for taking these photos.

There are many different ways of writing that caption depending on what you want to say exactly. You can also mention the kids' names if you know them, or if it's allowed by your policies.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this - I assume that they are obviously guest photos...

> Hitting the trails at Chalet Augustine - Mike and Anne's children
>   looking great in their ski suits!

Just one suggestion...